# GUI (client) freezes when creating chat from a combobox (chat client)

Tags: java, multithreading, combobox

I am creating a chat client which contains a class Server ( main class ) and a client class ( which starts a client and connects to the server ).

Then now I am trying to add a combobox with contacts before I connect a client to the server, so I did a new class for Combobox, with a actionListener and actionPerformed to open a client when pressing a contact. Problem is the Client that opens is running (seeing the printouts when messaging through Server ) but the Client GUI is gray and frozen, (like when a program does not answer). Same problem was with the combobox before I did dispose().

So I am currently quite new to thread coding, but my understanding of the problem (might be wrong) is that the Swing component thread which is used in the comboBoxClass is used on creating and clicking on contacts in the comboBox. When I then create a new Client in the comboBoxClass I already use the Swingthread there and the Client will not be able to use "enough" threads. Not sure thought but that is my conclusion.

Also here is a link to whole the code: https://pastebin.com/mNeBFn7q
(Using 4 textfiles so it wont run without them, but you will see the full structure).

```
};
class comboBoxClass {

 public comboBoxClass() {

     String[] favContacts = {
    "BigKarlos",
    "lilVillz",
    "metaforMatte",
    "BirkoStoteles",
    "Övriga Kontakter!!"

JComboBox contactList = new JComboBox(favContacts);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cont.add(contactList);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    contactList.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //contactList.addActionListener(this);

          ArrayList<String> arrayList = readFile();
            contentArr = new String[arrayList.size()];
            arrayList.toArray(contentArr);



            if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                port = contentArr[4];
                IP = contentArr[5];
            }
            if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                port = contentArr[7];
                IP = contentArr[8];
            }
            if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
                port = contentArr[1];
                IP = contentArr[2];
            }
            if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() == 3) {
                port = contentArr[10];
                IP = contentArr[11];

            }
            if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() == 4) {

             JFileChooser contactChooser = new JFileChooser("/Users/kasperknudsen/Documents/Chatten");
             contactChooser.getFileFilter();
             contactChooser.showOpenDialog(frame); 


            }

            frame.dispose();
            Client kontakt = new Client(IP,Integer.parseInt(port));

        }

    });
```

}

Comment: You must not call `startRunning` in the AWT event dispatch thread.  Because that method waits forever, it blocks all Swing events, including displaying and painting of windows, and responding to mouse and keyboard input.  Try `new Thread(this::startRunning).start();` instead.

Comment: I must thank you a lot, sat for 3 hours trying to identify the problem, I understood it but my knowledge was too low.